# Price calculations (tax and discount)

Tags: orocommerce

What is the correct way of calculating product (and order) prices when a coupon is applied (considering the product is taxable). I've noticed that the taxes and discounts are disconnected. They are both applied on product's row price (and then summed up for the total price). I need to apply the tax on discounted product price:

`(price - discount) + tax(discounted price)`

What is the best approach to implement such calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is not customizable from UI.

But you can change it in customization:

- Decorate [OrderLineItemMapper or OrderMapper](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/tree/4.1.4/src/Oro/Bundle/TaxBundle/OrderTax/Mapper), depending on your requirements
- Use there a price with an applied discount that you can fetch from `oro_promotion.promotion_executor` service.